# I just can't tell what is wrong with this Model code that save() is raising an exception.||

Tags: resource-model

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/760042/

My model object when passed to get_class appears to be ok.

```
2013-12-09T11:04:27-05:00 DEBUG (7):  get_class() Checkerboard_Workorder_Model_Workorderlineitem
```

The Object itself looks good too.

```
2013-12-09T11:04:27-05:00 DEBUG (7): workorderlineitem -> Checkerboard_Workorder_Model_Workorderlineitem Object 
( 
[_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract 
[_eventObject:protected] => object 
[_resourceName:protected] => workorder/workorderlineitem 
[_resource:protected] => 
[_resourceCollectionName:protected] => workorder/workorderlineitem_collection 
[_cacheTag:protected] => 
[_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1 
[_isObjectNew:protected] => 
[_data:protected] => Array 
( 
[workorder_id] => 6 
[udrop_ship_item_id] => 25 
[order_item_id] => 100 
[created_timestamp] => 1386605067 
) 

[_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1 
[_origData:protected] => 
[_idFieldName:protected] => 
[_isDeleted:protected] => 
[_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array 
( 
) 

[_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array 
( 
) 

)
```

But when I call save on the object the following exception is raised:

```
Can’t retrieve entity config: workorder/workorderlineitem 
#0 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(272): Mage::throwException(’Can’t retrieve ...’) 
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(284): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getTableName(’workorder/worko...’) 
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(247): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getTable(’workorderlineit...’) 
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(586): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getMainTable() 
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(449): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_prepareDataForSave(Object(Checkerboard_Workorder_Model_Workorderlineitem)) 
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Checkerboard_Workorder_Model_Workorderlineitem)) 
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/local/Checkerboard/Workorder/Model/Observer.php(125): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save() 
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/community/Unirgy/DropshipPo/Helper/Data.php(96): Checkerboard_Workorder_Model_Observer::createWorkorders(Array) 
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/community/Unirgy/DropshipPo/controllers/Adminhtml/PoController.php(80): Unirgy_DropshipPo_Helper_Data->sendVendorNotification(Object(Unirgy_DropshipPo_Model_Po)) 
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Unirgy_DropshipPo_Adminhtml_PoController->resendUdposAction() 
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch(’resendUdpos’) 
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) 
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() 
#13 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 
#14 /var/www/html/index.php(93): Mage::run(’’, ‘store’) 
#15 {main}
```

I am really confused by this, as everything looks to be ok in all of my code.

The official Magento forum has a link to download all of my code.

```
As requested the model section of my code.

       <models>
            <workorder>
                <class>Checkerboard_Workorder_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>workorder_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </workorder>

            <workorder_mysql4>
                <class>Checkerboard_Workorder_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <workorder>
                        <table>workorder</table>
                    </workorder>
                </entities>
            </workorder_mysql4>


            <workorderlineitem>
                <class>Checkerboard_Workorderlineitem_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>workorderlineitem_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </workorderlineitem>

            <workorderlineitem_mysql4>
                <class>Checkerboard_Workorderlineitem_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <workorderlineitem>
                        <table>workorder_lineitem</table>
                    </workorderlineitem>
                </entities>
            </workorderlineitem_mysql4>

            <picklistitem>
                <class>Checkerboard_Picklistitem_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>picklistitem_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </picklistitem>

            <picklistitem_mysql4>
                <class>Checkerboard_Picklistitem_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <picklistitem>
                        <table>picklist_items</table>
                    </picklistitem>
                </entities>
            </picklistitem_mysql4>

            <picklistproduct>
                <model>Checkerboard_Picklistproduct_Model</model>
                <resourceModel>picklistproduct_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </picklistproduct>
            <picklistproduct_mysql4>
                <class>Checkerboard_Picklistproduct_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <picklistproduct>
                        <table>picklist_products</table>
                    </picklistproduct>
                </entities>
            </picklistproduct_mysql4>
        </models>
```

```
// Model/Workorderlineitem.php

/**
 * Workorderlineitem object model.
 * @author Chris Pinto
 */
class Checkerboard_Workorder_Model_Workorderlineitem extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('workorder/workorderlineitem');
    }
}


// Model/Mysql4/Workorderlineitem.php


/**
 * Workorderlineitem object Mysql4 resource model.
 * @author Christopher Pinto
 */
class Checkerboard_Workorder_Model_Mysql4_Workorderlineitem extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract {
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('workorder/workorderlineitem', 'entity_id');
    }
}



// Model/Mysql4/Workorderlineitem/Collection.php/**
 * Workorderlineitem object Mysql4 resource model collection.
 * @author Christopher Pinto
 */
class Checkerboard_Workorder_Model_Mysql4_Workorderlineitem_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract {
    protected function _construct() {
        $this->_init('workorder/workorderlineitem');
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll find better help here if you post relevant code here instead a link to some zip file on another site. Did you find the following post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786371/cant-retrieve-entity-config

Comment: I saw that post last week and it did not help with my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your table name configuration you specified in the resource model's call to `_init()` can't be resolved in the configuration XML.
Update your post with the XML section under `global/models` to get more detailed information.

**UPDATE:**
I don't know the primary key column name for your take, so I'll just use `id` here. Substitute with your PK column name.

All in all your code is quite unusual because you

1. have declared multiple model class groups in one module config.xml
2. have a workorderlineitem and a workorder module, but also have a workorderlineitem model within your workorder module

So assuming all this is on purpose and you know what you are doing, your `_construct()` method of your resource model declaration for your workorder/workorderlineitem model should look like this:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('workorder/workorderlineitem', 'id');
}
```

That would resolve to the table name `workorder`.
That is, also assuming your resource model extends `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`, which it should.

To get more information, add your model and resource model classes (just the class declaration and the `__construct`/`_construct` methods.

**UPDATE 2:**
The resource model code you added explains the issue.
You use the following code to initialize the resource model:

```
$this->_init('workorder/workorderlineitem', 'entity_id');
```

But in your config XML you declare

```
...
<workorder_mysql4>
    <entities>
         <workorder><table>workorder</table></workorder>
    </entities>
</workorder_mysql4>
```

...

The part after the slash is mapped to a node within the `<entities>` node, which means you have to either use `$this->_init('workorder/workorder', 'entity_id');` in your resource model, or `.../workorder_mysql4/entities/workorderlineitem/table` in the config XML.

Comment: I added the config section as you requested.

Comment: I added the code sections that you have requested. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Answered the question in Update 2.

Comment: You need to revisit some Magento basics. You do not need to have several class groups for different models. You can have as many model/resource/collection triplets as you want within a single module.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

I have it all working now!